# Unexplained jQuery bug with scroll animation

Tags: javascript, html

I have a small problem with a short jQuery script.
I would like to create a simple scroll system, between 100% height section on my page.

I tried it, but there's a strange problem when using animate() jQuery function.

I've uploaded files on a server : http://www.fitnessmith.fr/test/

Try navigating through sections with links on right, and you'll see what I mean.

Here's the code used to create animations

```
$("nav#menu li a").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$(href).offset().top}, 600, 'easeInExpo');
});
```

Does anyone has an idea to solve it ? thanks for your help

Comment: When I click on any nav item in either Chrome or Opera, nothing happens - did you modify it again?

Comment: working fine in FF if this is the intended functionality :) do you want it to not scroll back to the top?

Comment: Thanks for your answer..
I just tried on Chrome and it totally doesn't work, thanks for noticing it

The problem is that if I click on "about" then I click back again on "about" it goes to the top. OR if I click on "about", then, on "works", nothing happens. Did you notice it ?

Comment: It's so weird, if you press the Contact nav it goes between about and works..

Comment: yes, another strange thing...Yet my code is really short and simple..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are applying `overflow: hidden` to both `html` and `body` elements. If you remove the `overflow` from your `html,body` rule, only the document body element will be `overflow:hidden` by virtue of your specific `body` rule.

The reason why this happened is that when you animated the `scrollTop` property of both `html` and `body`, due to neither having overflow and thus unable to truly scroll, what changed was the *content* of `body` relative to their offset parent.

You can see this in action if you called `$('#about').offset()` after clicking the link once. It reports a top position of 0! What has happened is that the "top" of your page has simply moved up in order to scroll the content to the viewport while maintaining no overflow. `$('#home').offset()` reports a large negative top at that point to indicate this.

By removing the `html,body { overflow: hidden; }` rule, you are allowing the content to be scrolled against a container while the more specific `body { overflow: hidden; }` rule hides the scrollbars.

Comment: Thanks my friend. Let me try it and I will tell you. But thanks for your help, you're a master !